# Clean up bound property

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have IVector collection property which is bound with xaml element.

```
using PlatformStringVector = Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Platform::String^>^;
```

The collection member :

```
PlatformStringVector m_dataCollection = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
```

The Property :

```
property PlatformStringVector DataCollection
{
  PlatformStringVector get() { return m_dataCollection; }
  void set(PlatformStringVector value) { SetProperty(m_dataCollection, value, "DataCollection");}
}
```

I am trying to clean the collection from background thread. If i am clearing the bound property i am getting error from xaml is null.

```
DataCollection->Clear();
```

But if the clean up is done by

```
m_dataCollection->Clear().
```

Everything works fine.

What is the difference between Property Clear and data driven clear?

```
/// <summary>Initializes the session asynchronous.</summary>
void App::InitSessionAsync()
{
    concurrency::create_task([this]
    {
        WaitForDevice();
    }).then([this](concurrency::task<void> task)
    {
        try
        {
            task.get();
        }
        catch (const Polytec::IO::CommunicationException & ex)
        {
            ..
        }

        AppData::ViewModel->DataCollection->Clear(); // This clear does not work.             
        //AppData::ViewModel->ClearCollection(); // It actually clears the data collection member. And this works

        auto rootFrame = dynamic_cast<Frame^>(Window::Current->Content);
        rootFrame->Navigate(TypeName(MainPage::typeid), nullptr, ref new Animation::SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo);
    }, concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_current());
}
```

Comment: When I tested the code in the UI thread, the Property Clear worked well. If you don't clean the collection from background thread, will the same issue occur? And can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT This is hard to share the full picture in example code. My situation is the Clear doesn't work from background thread. But if I clear the member it works. What is the difference between bound property Clear and clear of the member itself? Even replacing/modifying the Property works. Please see edit. I shared what i am doing from background thread.

Comment: The [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/property-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019) behaves like a data member. I used your method and cleared the DataCollection, it worked well. And how you created your  background thread?